# How to send the remaining chunks

Tags: c#, streaming

Web API only returns first chunk. How do I get the next chunk (remaining chunks).

Web API output:

{"content":"IxMi8yMy8yMDIyIDEzOjE3OjI2LjAzMiJ9DQp7InBDb25zdCI6MC44LCJsb2dNTcuNTE0In0NCg==","set":225000,"len":15286}

Comment: Are you using .net framework or .net core?

Comment: My target framework is net5.0. Which is a version of .net core.

Comment: What or where is the `BLOBStream` type? Have you looked at returning `FileStreamResult` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly do you mean by:

> Which stops from sending remaining chunks

Do you expect the method to return chunk after chunk on one call? Or do you call the method for each chunk (like it seems to be designed)?

I think you may need too add [FromQuery] attribute on both '**offset**' and '**blobLengthRemaining**' parameters in your controller. You would call your controller method with:

1. GET  api/controller/file_name_to_get (the query is omitted)
2. GET  api/controller/file_name_to_get?offset=1048576&blobLengthRemaining=315286

P.S. Maybe the [memorymappedviewaccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor?view=net-7.0) can be useful for your case

Answer (score 0):

In this situation using the WEB command would show the reaming chunks.